# How do I list only directories created based on a date range. Basically, I will pick a start-date and an end-date using WPF /C#?

Tags: c#

I have this code that lists all the subdirectories in a folder.

```
string path = @"C:\Temp\MyFolder";
DirectoryInfo dir_place = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectoryInfo[] directories = dir_place.GetDirectories();
foreach (var directory in directories)
 {
    listBox.Items.Add(directory.Name);
 }
```

Comment: using `directory.CreationTime` perhaps? (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime)

Comment: You should be calling `EnumerateDirectories` and then `Where` on the result to filter based on the appropriate property value. You should know what properties the `DirectoryInfo` type has because you should have read the relevant documentation. You can then bind those filtered results to your `ListBox`.

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution

```
// Define the start and end date from xaml wpf
DateTime startDate = StartDatePicker.SelectedDate ?? DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime endDate = EndDatePicker.SelectedDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue;

// Get an array of directories in the specified folder
string[] directories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(folderPath);

// Filter the directories based on creation date
IEnumerable<string> filteredDirectories = directories.Where(directory =>
    DateTime.Compare(System.IO.Directory.GetCreationTime(directory), startDate) >= 0 &&
    DateTime.Compare(System.IO.Directory.GetCreationTime(directory), endDate) <= 0);

// Iterate through each filtered directory
foreach (string directory in filteredDirectories)
{
    Console.WriteLine(directory);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Frenchy
Just what I was looking for!!

Comment: @user2835586 happy to help you, dont forget to validate/update the answer to close the question..Thanks